# How do I create an offline version of my Website?

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, offline

Is there a way to generate offline version of the whole Website?

All my pages are in ASPX and uploaded onto the server. When I run a demo of my site, sometimes there are no Internet availability. So it would be great to actually have the site offline but not running Visual Studio in order to show the site.

Anyone has a way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is your website content static or dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to run the site locally on your machine, you can just configure the project in visual studio to run using IIS (Right click on project, go to web and select to use the local IIS server).

You can then access it using http://localhost/

if you don't have IIS installed, there is an IIS express version that you can use:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/06/28/introducing-iis-express.aspx

Comment: Is IIS Express standalone installer out yet? I can't seem to find it on Googl. Thank you.

Comment: @Jason - have you had a look at Scott Gu's blog - that'd be the place to find a link.

Comment: If you don't have IIS installed, your first try should be "Programs and Functions" => "Turn Windows Features on or off" => "Internet Information Services"...

Answer (score 1):

You can install Microsoft IIS onto your system, and copy your site files into the "wwwhttpdocs" folder in the IIS Directory.

then you can request your site in any web browser like this example:

http://localhost:48719(somePort)/YourSiteName(SiteFolderName)/default.aspx

if you are running on Windows, you can install MS IIS from the control panel as a windows component